# Firemonkey message handling using TMessageManager and TThread.Queue

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

Like many other Firemonkey developers, I need a general multi-platform solution to send messages from a thread to the main thread (to replace PostMessage). I need it to also work on iOS.

There is a solution by François Piette that is implemented for Android and Windows, but not for iOS: 
[TMessagingSystem](http://francois-piette.blogspot.dk/2013/12/firemonkey-android-windows-and.html).

However, I think it can be done much more simple by using the "new" TMessageManager in combination with TThread.Queue(). But no one have published code, using this aproach, that actually works (e.g. [this one is not complete](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/ios-and-tmessage-from-a-thread/1052957)).

Do you have a tested implementation you would like to share with the community (or maybe just suggestions how to implement it right)?

Comment: Use `TThread.Queue` and closures. Both work on any platform. http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/

Comment: Note that `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` were broken in *every* version of FireMonkey prior to XE7.  See [QC #123579](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123579) for details and a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is my implementation. I did not use TMessagingSystem as it seems to just add complexity (for my situation at least). It works so far, but if anyone have suggestions for improvements, I will be happy to improve it.

I looked at the solution by [Uwe Raabe](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/) but I wanted to make it more straightforward and easy to implement in the large codebase that I am converting to FMX.
With the solution below I can simply replace all PostMessage() with gMessageHandler.PostMessage (removing the win handle argument), and add the message functions in the form to tMainForm.MessageCallBack.

I created a small unit that I can include everywhere I need the PostMessage function. Those places does not need to know about the form:

```
unit MessageHandler
interface
tAllOSMessage = procedure(aMessageID, aData1, aData2: integer) of object;
tAllOSMessageHandler = class
private
  fOnMessage : tAllOSMessage;
public
  constructor Create(aMessageCallBack: tAllOSMessage);
  procedure PostMessage(aMessageID, aData1, aData2: integer; aSourceThread: TThread = nil);
end;

var
  gMessageHandler: tAllOSMessageHandler;

implementation

constructor tAllOSMessageHandler.Create(aMessageCallBack: tAllOSMessage);
begin
  fOnMessage := aMessageCallBack;
end;

procedure tAllOSMessageHandler.PostMessage(aMessageID, aData1, aData2: integer; aSourceThread: TThread);
begin
  if aSourceThread=nil then
    aSourceThread := TThread.CurrentThread;
  aSourceThread.Queue(nil, procedure
                           begin
                             if Assigned(fOnMessage) then
                               fOnMessage(aMessageID, aData1, aData2);
                           end  );
end;
end.
```

Then I add these lines to the main form unit:

```
//Added to main form:
tMainForm = class(TForm)
...
procedure MessageCallBack(aMessageID, aData1, aData2: integer);

//Added to MainFormCreate
gMessageHandler := tAllOSMessageHandler.Create(MessageCallBack);

//Added to MainFormDestroy
FreeAndNil(gMessageHandler)

procedure tMainForm.MessageCallBack(aMessageID, aData1, aData2: integer);
begin
  case aMessageID of
    MyMessage1 :  MyFunction1(aData1,aData2);
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you bother with the aSourceThread? Simply use TThread.Queue(nil, ...) it's basically the same thing.

Comment: @ciuly: Great, then the source code can become even more simple :-) I don't recall why the aSourceThread came in.